# mysql Cannot add 2 Foreign Keys

Tags: php, mysql, sql, windows

I'm writing a script for an associative table in MySQL and It stops compiling at the second foreign key constraint; does anyone know what could be wrong? Please, I would appreciate it!

```
create table Adviser(
    AdviserID integer not null,
    LastName char(25) not null,
    FirstName char(25) not null,
    AdviserEmail varchar(100) not null,
    OfficePhoneNumber char(12) not null,
    constraint Adviser_pk primary key(AdviserID),
    constraint Adviser_fk foreign key(OfficePhoneNumber)
        references Department(OfficePhoneNumber)
            on delete no action 
            on update no action
);

create table Student(
    StudentID integer not null,
    LastName char(25) not null,
    FirstName char(25) not null,
    StudentEmail varchar(100) not null,
    EnrollmentDate date not null,
    GradDate date not null,
    Degree char(25) not null,
    DormPhoneNumber char(12) not null,
    constraint Student_pk primary key(StudentID),
    constraint Student_fk foreign key(DormPhoneNumber)
        references Dorm(DormPhoneNumber)
            on delete no action 
            on update no action
);
```

**The two tables above work fine, when I make the table below link to the two above something goes wrong with having 2 foreign keys**

```
create table AppointmentDate1(
    AdviserID integer not null,
    StudentID integer not null,
    StudentAppointmentDate date not null,
    StudentEndDate date not null,
    constraint AppointmentDate1_pk primary key(AdviserID, StudentID),
    constraint AppointmentDate1_fk foreign key(AdviserID)
        references Adviser(AdviserID)
            on delete no action 
            on update no action,
        constraint AppointmentDate1_fk foreign key(StudentID)
        references Student(StudentID)
            on delete no action 
            on update no action
);
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What error message do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rename two foreign keys, it should work just as below..
I tested it using the following create table script on my local database and I could create AppointmentDate1 table successfully.

```
create table AppointmentDate1(
    AdviserID integer not null,
    StudentID integer not null,
    StudentAppointmentDate date not null,
    StudentEndDate date not null,
    constraint AppointmentDate1_pk primary key(AdviserID, StudentID),
    constraint AdviserId1_fk foreign key(AdviserID)
        references Adviser(AdviserID)
            on delete no action 
            on update no action,
        constraint StudentId1_fk foreign key(StudentID)
        references Student(StudentID)
            on delete no action 
            on update no action
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked! This community is great!

Answer (score 3):

Foreign keys need to have different constraint names.  Try this:

```
create table AppointmentDate1(
    AdviserID integer not null,
    StudentID integer not null,
    StudentAppointmentDate date not null,
    StudentEndDate date not null,
    constraint AppointmentDate1_pk primary key(AdviserID, StudentID),
    constraint fk_AppointmentDate1_AdviserId foreign key(AdviserID)
        references Adviser(AdviserID)
            on delete no action 
            on update no action,
        constraint fk_AppointmentDate1_StudentId foreign key(StudentID)
        references Student(StudentID)
            on delete no action 
            on update no action
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked! This community is great!